# How to compute (or upper bound) the expected value of power of the sum of product of Gaussian iid random variables?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $g_{1t}, g_{2t}, \ldots, g_{nt}$ are i.i.d. random samples from standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$, where $n$ is an integer and $t\in [T]$. For any $k>2$, how to compute the exact value or an upper bound of the  following expression:
$$
E \left[ \left|\sum_{t=1}^{T} g_{1t}\cdot g_{2t} \cdot \ldots \cdot g_{nt}\right|^{k} \right].
$$

Comment: This is such a dramatic change from your original version of the question that I wonder what your real question might be.  Where does this expression come from?

Comment: Title doesn't match the body; the expression in the body is not the first moment (i.e. not the expected value of the sum of the products as mentioned in the title).